# Is it possible to create Form Components programmatically in Install4j 7

Tags: install4j

I am trying to create a form that requires quite a large amount of components but I do not want to create them all manually. Is there a way to create these components using a Form's Pre-activation script or some other script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of install4j 7, form components have to be configured statically in the IDE, there is no way to create them at runtime.

You can develop your own form component with the API that exiibits dynamic behavior, see the `samples/customCode` project for an example on how to get started.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. Where exactly do I develop the code? Do I create a separate Java project? I'm not seeing much in the Install4j pdf.

Comment: Yes, you have to set up a separate project. The install4j API is is ì4jruntime.jar`. Please see the overview page of the javadoc https://resources.ej-technologies.com/install4j/help/api/ for more information.